# Testing image uploads in Wikimedia Commons

Tags: mediawiki, pywikibot, wikimedia-commons

I want to use `pywikibot` to upload a batch of images into Wikimedia Commons.
However, when you add images in Commons, you can't easily delete them if you made a mistake.
Is there a way to locally install Wikimedia Commons for validation and testing ?

I tried installing `mediawiki`, but I can't seem to upload images using `pywikibot`.

Is there some specific procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way more effort than just uploading and saying sorry if it goes wrong (just don't do batch operations until you are reasonably confident the script works; also see [Guide to batch uploading](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Guide_to_batch_uploading) and [bot requests](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Bots/Requests) if you haven't yet). Also, licensing tends to be just as easy to get wrong as the technology; if you are not sure about what you are doing, ask first.

You can also use the [test wiki](https://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) for testing the bot (but no mass uploads please, just a few test files). Note it does not support structured data in image descriptions, unlike Commons. (There is a [Commons test wiki](https://test-commons.wikimedia.org/) but not for long.)

If you want to install a local MediWiki anyway, the `mediawiki` package is the easiest way (it will be dissimilar from Commons in a number of ways, but most of them probably don't matter much), make sure it is [properly configured for uploading](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads) (not sure if the Debian package does that out of the box), then [generate a wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Use_on_third-party_wikis) for pywikipediabot.